# Using Squeeze Theorem to show the following limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider a function f (x) defined on R satisfying:
[image]

for all x distinct 0. 
**Calculate**: lim f(x) with x→∞ and limf(x) with x→−∞

- Issue information:

if x → ∞ then we can consider | x | = x

if x → -∞ then we can consider | x | = -x

I can use x² = | x |?

Answer (score 2):

$x^2\ne |x|$. The formula gives you

$$\frac{7^2+5x|x|+2}{x^2+16}-\frac{1}{x^2}\leq f(x)\leq \frac{7^2+5x|x|+2}{x^2+16}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

You can use the fact that $x|x|=x^2$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $x|x|=-x^2$ when $x\rightarrow -\infty$. Also $\frac{1}{x^2}\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Comment: I am not sure whether your $7^2$ is a typo though.

Comment: It is not an error, the expression contain 7²

Comment: I see. Just a comment. That doesn't really affect the answer.